# Registry in non-English language versions of Windows

Tags: windows, registry, non-english

in my application I want to use data from
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`
I'm afraid it will not work in for example the Chinese/Japenese-language version of Windows. Are these values always in English? I am talking about following keys
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` > `ProductName`
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` > `EditionID`

Can someone with access to such systems check it for me? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe these values are translated.  However, don't use the registry to retrieve product version information. Use the APIs that provide this information.

[GetVersionEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx)

[GetProductInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Version helper functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx)

[WMI: Win32_OperatingSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx)